# extending urlize in django

Tags: django

the urlize function from django.utils.html converts urls to clickable links. My problem is that I want to append a target="_blank" into the "< href..>", so that I open this link in a new tab. Is there any way that I can extend the urlize function to receive an extra argument? or should I make a custom filter using regexes to do this stuff? Is this efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no capability in the built-in `urlize()` to do this. Due to Django's license you can copy the code of `django.utils.html.urlize` and `django.template.defaultfilters.urlize` into your project or into a separate app and use the new definitions instead.

Answer (score 68):

You can add a custom filter, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags):

I used this one:

```
# <app name>/templatetags/url_target_blank.py

from django import template
register = template.Library()

def url_target_blank(text):
    return text.replace('<a ', '<a target="_blank" ')

url_target_blank = register.filter(url_target_blank, is_safe = True)
```

Example of usage:

```
{% load url_target_blank %}
...
{{ post_body|urlize|url_target_blank }}
```

Works fine for me :)

Comment: I had to add: url_target_blank.is_safe = True  to prevent django escaping the link.

Comment: To allow broader use of url_target_blank and to make it slightly tighter: I would use a regular expresion in the return line:
def url_target_blank(value):
   return re.sub("<a([^>]+)(?<!target=)>",'<a target="_blank"\\1>',value)

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, this should have been the accepted answer

Comment: I would also use a regexp as replacing every "<a " is a bit too generic for my taste. You should also set url_target_blank.is_safe = True.

Comment: @GrahamKing could you edit the answer to show where this needs to be added?

Comment: If automatically parsing user-entered text, you'll also want to set `rel="noopener"` to prevent some vulnerabilities ([as described here](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/))

Comment: Good suggestion by Boaz, but for the uninitiated, do remember that `re.sub` will perform around 10x slower than `replace()` in many cases (I've personally benchmarked it). However the former's accuracy advantage over the latter cannot be denied.

Answer (score 16):

Shortest version, that I use in my projects. Create a new filter, that extends the default filter of Django:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import urlize as urlize_impl

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True, needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def urlize_target_blank(value, limit, autoescape=None):
    return mark_safe(urlize_impl(value, trim_url_limit=int(limit), nofollow=True, autoescape=autoescape).replace('<a', '<a target="_blank"'))
```

Comment: You also need `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`

Comment: oh so you can indeed extend the builtin templatetag?

Comment: `urlize` has trim_url_limit=None. So I added None as the default: `urlize_target_blank(value, limit=None, autoescape=None)`

Answer (score -4):

You shouldn't add `target="_blank"` to your links, it's deprecated. Users should decide themselves if where they want to open a link.

You can still open the link with unobtrusive JavaScript like so (using jQuery):

```
$('.container a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();window.open(this.href);});
```

That said, you could write your own filter, but you'd have to copy a lot of code from `django.utils.html.urlize`, not really [DRY](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry).

Comment: Not deprecated anymore in HTML5.

Comment: "Not deprecated anymore in HTML5" That's true. W3Schools says [HTML5 Tag A](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_a.asp) and another article says [XHTML deprecated A target tag](http://www.infranet.com/_blog/Complete_Website_Optimization_Blog/post/Replacing_the_XHTML_deprecated_a_target_tag/)

Comment: W3Schools is not a good source. Rather directly go to the spec.

Comment: You are right on w3schools. Here's a source that deserves trust: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a
`The target attribute on the a element was deprecated in a previous version of HTML, but is no longer deprecated, as it useful in Web applications, particularly in combination with the iframe element.`

Comment: @ stefanw ... I would argue exactly opposite of what you are proposing. There is no reason to choose a JavaScript method when there is a non-JS method that is better... I'd actually say that in a non-JS web app (a web site in HTML, PHP, Python, etc), you shouldn't use JavaScript unless you have to ( [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) )...