# Template mark-up hyperlinks from plain text

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a template filter in django that does the following:

```
text = 'hello please visit this site: www.google.com.'
```

And turns it in the template to:

```
hello please visit this site: <a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a template filter does this job

```
{{ text|urlize }}
```

If `text` variable is **"hello please visit this site: www.google.com"**,

And the *output* will be

`"hello please visit this site: <a href="www.google.com" rel="nofollow">www.google.com</a>"`.

**Update :**  Click here for [target="_blank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295725/extending-urlize-in-django)

Comment: Perfect, is there a way to open the links in a new window. That is, `<a target="_blank">` ?