# How to extract hashtag form a user post/string?

Tags: python, django

i want to parse a string from a user input that has #hashtag and print out the result together with other words too

just the way facebook and twitter handles it :)

for example:
a user posts

> " hello #word, am learning #python and #django today! "

i want the out put to be:
 hello [#word](/hastag/word), am learning [#python](/hastag/python) and [#django](/hashtag/django) today!

this is how far i've gone:

```
@login_required
@ajax_required
def post(request):
    last_feed = request.POST.get('last_feed')

    user = request.user
    csrf_token = (csrf(request)['csrf_token'])
    feed = Feed()
    feed.user = user
    post = request.POST['post']

    lookup_hash_tag =  post.strip()
    hstg=re.compile(r"#(\w+)")
    #print pat.findall(s)

    for hashtag in hstg.findall(lookup_hash_tag):

        post = "<span><a href='/hastag/?q={}'>{}</a> </span> {}".format(hashtag, hashtag,  post.replace('#', '#'))




    if len(post) > 0:
        feed.post = post[:255]
        feed.save()
    html = _html_feeds(last_feed, user, csrf_token)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: You need to be very specific in your questions otherwise you'll continue to get down votes.

Comment: Try creating custom filter, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507447/3762142 and https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2072/ this is your starting point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no real idea about your question but I see a few things wrong:

- Instead of the for loop over the matches this can be used: `re.sub(r'#([\w]+)', r"<span><a href='/hastag/?q=\g<1>'>#\g<1></a> </span>", a)`
- The `post` variable gets overridden in the for loop every time.
- What is feed?
- Lot of extra complexity (`post.replace('#', '#')` does nothing, having brackets around a variable does nothing, etc)
- If the feed is a model, why not making the `post` field bigger? If you cut at 255, you might loose data (or cut in a middle of a link for example)

Please provide more info otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, why did you answer? You should comment asking for clarification and/or flag the question as unclear instead.