# Django: a custom template tag to convert links inside of a TextField and change the hyperlink text

Tags: django, django-templates

The scenario is that there are some dynamic texts on some templates, that will contain hyperlinks.
For this, I have a `SiteDataKeyValue` model, in which the dynamic texts for different parts of the template are inputted. This is the model:

```
class SiteDataKeyValue(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, verbose_name="نام متن مورد نظر", unique=True
    )
    value = models.TextField(verbose_name="متن")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

A solution that I've found already, is Django [urlize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) template tag. As mentioned in the docs, this tag converts texts like `https://www.google.com` to `<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">www.google.com</a>`, which is nice but not what I'd like to achieve. I want to be able to change the hyperlink text, so the output would be something like: `<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">Click Here!</a>`.

I searched for a bit, came across modules like [bleach](https://pypi.org/project/bleach/), which is a fine module, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for (I skimmed through the docs and there was nothing about the hyperlink text).

Also I saw a comment somewhere telling that this could be achieved by writing a `custom Django template tag`, but although I tried to do this regarding the [custom template filters docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), I didn't have a clue to how to achieve this.

I'm not asking for the code, although it would be really appreciated if you provide instructions for writing this custom template tag, or better, if you could point me to something like this that is already out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on a completely wrong road to solve this problem. I was trying to urlize a link from TextField, but didn't consider the fact that I only needed to implement html code as `<a href="https://www.link.com">Visit link.com!</a>` in the TextField, and then use `safe` template tag to render html directly as below:

```
{{ text.value|safe }}
```

So in this solution, there is no need to `urlize`, and of course there is no need to extend this tag neither.

NOTE: As commented by @rahimz ([link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74860291/django-a-custom-template-tag-to-convert-links-inside-of-a-textfield-and-change#comment132136350_74861107)) I understand that there are safety concerns regarding `safe` tag, So I should emphasize that only me and a company-trusted admin will have access to admin panel and there is no worries that this admin will send malicious code through this TextField.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can extend urlize tag like the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507447)

or you can change the main code which you can find it in **django.utils.html** and override its url variable to change it.

But I think the best method is extending the urlize tag
like this:

`{% text | urlize | change_a_text_filter:{{ dome_new_a_text }} %}`

then you can scrape the text and use regex to find `>sample-text</a>` then you can change it to the argument that defines in your tag

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def change_a_text_filter(format_string, arg):
    # find the url that made in urlize with regex
    # change it with arg
    # return the result
```

Comment: Although this approach is correct, but before completing this route, I consulted another friend with the main problem, and he propposed `safe` template tag to render html directly from TextField :); an extremely easy method which I think I was strayed from because I was looking for another solution in my mind.

Comment: @Vahid it is a good way but you should consider that `safe` tag has some security considerations, with this tag you give the access to the user to run any kind of script. So if you know the user and it is "safe" to give them this privilege, go on :)

Comment: Yes @rahimz, I didn't mention that only me and company-trusted admin can have access to admin panel. So thank you for the tip, and rest assured that this issue has been considered. Also I edited my answer and mentioned your concern regarding this issue.